# Regular Expression remove specific words in any order

Tags: regex, perl, words, option-type, substitution

I want to substitute (remove) specific optional words (AAA, BBB, CCC) which are in any order immediately before and after a specific word (ALWAYS_THERE)

```
this is important AAA BBB ALWAYS_THERE CCC
this is important BBB AAA ALWAYS_THERE CCC
this is important AAA CCC ALWAYS_THERE BBB
this is important BBB ALWAYS_THERE CCC AAA
this is important BBB this also ALWAYS_THERE CCC AAA
```

to

```
this is important
this is important
this is important
this is important
this is important BBB this also
```

How can this be done in perl (or any other on UNIX available program)?

Comment: That's not really fair. This is a newbie question, but it seems clearly to be about "how can I write a regular expression to match the pattern that I've described", which isn't entirely trivial. It's important to read `perlintro` but it's extremely unlikely that it's going to help the questioner with this specific problem.

Comment: @qwrrty - I suspect the 'fairness' arrives by citing those resources to 1) encourage the OP to show solution attempts and 2) develop fishing skills, instead of merely handing the OP a fish.  How meaningful can any of the provided solutions be w/o a (minimal) regex foundation?

Comment: I'm all in favor of feeding people by teaching them to fish, but this is more like feeding them by teaching them to rub two sticks together. A link to a [regular expression tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) would at least be more appropriate to the problem than `perlintro`.

Comment: @qwrrty - I disagree.  The very first sentence of the *Regular expressions* section of `perlintro` says: "Perl's regular expression support is both broad and deep, and is the subject of lengthy documentation in [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and elsewhere."  Both resources cited in this first sentence are good and appropriate places to begin building a regex foundation.

Comment: Too many unanswered questions to write a valid regex.

Comment: @sln this is the place to ask the questions, then

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
s/\b(AAA\s+|BBB\s+|CCC\s+)*ALWAYS_THERE(\s+AAA|\s+BBB|\s+CCC)*\b//g;
```

[edited to add leading and trailing `\b` per @ikegami]

Comment: You should probably consider adding an \s+ quantifier to the end of this pattern or "something AAA ALWAYS_THERE BBB else" will be converted to "something  else". And this is somewhat a matter of taste, but I prefer building regexes (see my answer) instead of hardcoding them, when possible.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be wrong to transform "something AAA ALWAYS_THERE BBB else" into "something else". As I read the OP's request, that would be a correct answer. It's up to them.

Comment: Should put a leading and trailing `\b` or something. Not only will it prevent `xAAA` in `xAAA ALWAYS_THERE` from being removed, it will reduce backtracking. There's also the issue of resulting in two adjacent spaces.

Comment: leaves a trailing space (e.g. "this is important ")

Answer (score 2):

try this pattern `(\s*(AAA|BBB|CCC))*\s*ALWAYS_THERE.*$`
[demo](http://regex101.com/r/oY0hL4)

Comment: But your demo shows the substitution fails for `this is important BBB this also ALWAYS_THERE CCC AAA`.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex in perl (assuming only a single space of separation between words):

```
s/(.*)((?:(AAA|BBB|CCC) )*ALWAYS_THERE.*)/$1/
```

if you need to NOT chop off certain things after the "ALWAYS_THERE" part that do not match AAA or BBB or CCC, then use this one:

```
s/(.*)(?:(?:(?:AAA|BBB|CCC) )*ALWAYS_THERE(?: (?:AAA|BBB|CCC))*)(.*)/$1$2/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
s/((?:\s+(?:AAA|BBB|CCC))*)\s+ALWAYS_THERE\g<1>//g
```

However a string like : `"This is important ALWAYS_THERE"` is replaced by `"This is important"`.

If you want to avoid this behavior you can use this other pattern:

```
s/((?:\s+(?:AAA|BBB|CCC))+)? ALWAYS_THERE(\g<1>)?(?(1)|(?(2)|(?!)))//g
```

Answer (score -1):

This amounts to the same thing as the other answers, but there are some advantages--in particular, adding more ignore tokens is less error prone (since you only have to add them to an array; the regex is built from the array and `$always_there` automatically:

```
my $always_there = 'ALWAYS_THERE';
my @ignore = (
    'AAA',
    'BBB',
    'CCC',
);

my $ig_str = '('.join('|', map { "$_\\b\\s*" } @ignore).')*';

$data =~ s/$ig_str$always_there\s+$ig_str//; #Add /g modifier if ALWAYS_THERE can appear > once
```